# Could not find method android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor

Tags: android

On devices under 5.0 I'm getting the following error:

```
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor, referenced from method onCreateView
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14897: Landroid/view/Window;.setStatusBarColor (I)V
```

and the code is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: Is there another code occurence where you try to set the status bar color but not wrap it in code like above?

Comment: no that's the only place, that's why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way! 
It is working for me. Hope works for you too.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, this.getTheme()));
            window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white, this.getTheme()));
        }
```